# How to split a single file into multiple text files in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a text file:

```
1003  24015
1003  24016
1003  24017
1004  24018
1004  24019
```

I want to split this file into two text files programmatically, which should produce the results as below:

`first.txt`:

```
1003  24015
1003  24016
1003  24017
```

`second.txt`:

```
1004  24018
1004  24019
```

Comment: And what's the criterion for a value to go into `first` or `second`? Value of the first column? The first half of rows?

Comment: AND what research have you done to solve your problem? Post some code and we can help you fix it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily split a file by the first column with `awk`:

```
awk '{ print > $1 ".txt" }' yourfile
```

In your case, this would create the files `1003.txt` and `1004.txt` (and similar for any other first columns), each containing the lines starting with that value.

Comment: What if I have to do the split on column 1 but just want the output of column 2 in the text file.

Comment: Unlike your posted example? To just write the second column, use `{ print $2 > $1 ".txt" }`