# Split text file into multiple text files based on column values with sequential names in unix

Tags: unix

I have a similar problem to solve to this: [How to split a single file into multiple text files in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657939/how-to-split-a-single-file-into-multiple-text-files-in-unix) . But I would like to have output text files named in a sequential way not the value in the column.

I have a very big tab-delimited text file:

```
A 2
A 4
B 4
B 6
A 1
C 5
```

I want to split this file into a number of text files in unix based on the first column, but the files would not be named by the column value like the suggested solution in the link above i.e.:

```
awk '{print $0 >> ($1 ".txt"); close($1 ".txt")}'
```

The output should be:

```
tmp1.txt
```

```
A 2
A 4
A 1
```

```
tmp2.txt
```

```
B 4
B 6
```

```
tmp3.txt
```

```
C 5
```

and so on for each value in the first column.

Comment: I have a question about what you mean by "sequential". If the file contains no lines starting with "E", would you want the lines starting with "F" to be written to `tmp5.txt` or `tmp6.txt`?

Comment: Yes. I mean these are not necessarily E, F, and so on, and the order can be different to alphabetical one...but the output would be tmp5, tmp6, and so on, in order of the value appearing in the input text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output to a new, sequentially-named tmp file every time there's a new value in the first column.

```
awk 'BEGIN { i = 1 }
     function seq(col1) {
         if (!(col1 in map))
             map[col1] = i++;
         return map[col1]; 
     }
     { print $0 >> ("tmp" seq($1) ".txt"); close("tmp" seq($1) ".txt") }'
```

After running with your sample input:

```bash
$ head tmp*
==> tmp1.txt <==
A 2
A 4
A 1

==> tmp2.txt <==
B 4
B 6

==> tmp3.txt <==
C 5
```